# MySQL union missing parenthesis

Tags: mysql, sql

I dont get it. I try to sum up two identical tables with union but it doesnt works.

```
t_fb_data:

id | date      | sum
---------------------
1  | 2017.01.01| 2
2  | 2017.01.02| 1

t_google_data:

id | date      | sum
---------------------
1  | 2017.01.01| 7
2  | 2017.01.02| 1
3  | 2017.01.03| 2

result could looks like:

| date      | sum
------------------
| 2017.01.01| 2
| 2017.01.02| 1
| 2017.01.01| 7
| 2017.01.02| 1
| 2017.01.03| 2
```

This is my Query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT date
            , sum 
         FROM t_fb_data
     ) T1 
 Union 
     ( SELECT date
            , sum 
         FROM t_google_data
     ) T2
```

T2 should be wrong because my workbench want an parenthesis in front of T2. But if i do this its wrong two. Do i have to setup something on my workbench?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You try to union two subqueries having `SELECT` statement at top refering to first subquery.

Code that You are looking for:

```
SELECT date, sum FROM t_fb_data
UNION
SELECT date, sum FROM t_google_data
```

That will return non duplicated values from both tables.

If you want to use this as a subquery, you can simply surround that with another `SELECT` statement as on example below:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
SELECT date, sum FROM t_fb_data
UNION
SELECT date, sum FROM t_google_data
) sub
```

In this case, You can do additonal calculations in your top `SELECT` statement, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
SELECT 
    date, sum
FROM
    t_fb_data 
UNION SELECT 
    date, sum
FROM
    t_google_data
```

or put it in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        date, sum
    FROM
        t_fb_data UNION SELECT 
        date, sum
    FROM
        t_google_data) t;
```

Comment: the first one works. but if i want to add some where clauses i have to do it on every subquery. the second one needs an own alias on every select

Comment: @nicoschuck Sorry. Updated now.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, if you want to sum up identical values from different data sets, you need to use the keyword ALL, because the union alone will sum up the data sets in an unique data sets and apply a DISTINCT on it.
Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT date,sum FROM t_fb_data Union ALL SELECT date,sum FROM t_google_data
```

Comment: Actually it could works with union too. the problem is if i want to add some WHere clauses or if i want to group the data i have to write it on every string.

Comment: So you have to put the other columns on both of your queries, in order to make them visible outside the inline view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL for sure,
but if you want to stick to UNION only then try this,

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT date
            , sum, 'fb' identifier 
         FROM t_fb_data
     ) T1 
 Union 
     ( SELECT date
            , sum, 'google' identifier 
         FROM t_google_data
     ) T2
```

This is because, your data from two queries will give identical records which will be merged into single record, so if you will write identifer both tables will have differential records.

I hope this will help.

**EDIT**

```
 ( SELECT date
            , sum, 'fb' identifier 
         FROM t_fb_data
     )  
 Union 
     ( SELECT date
            , sum, 'google' identifier 
         FROM t_google_data
     )
```

Comment: i get this Error: 17:12:49 T2 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T2' at line 11